# Adaptive Control Block Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I have done control block diagrams on LaTeX, and I am trying to figure out how to draw the model reference adaptive control block diagram:

[image]

I don't know how to draw the slash across the controller to the reference model block. Can one show me how to do so?

Comment: You will get almost instantly an answer if you post what you have. Otherwise others will have to start from scratch. If the controller has the name `c`, say, use `\draw[-latex] ([yshift=-1em]c.south west) -- ([yshift=1em]c.north east);`.

Comment: Ti*k*Z is very large and complex, but for many simple tasks Cremer's [tutorial](https://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) helps a lot over the first (most?) speed bumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
        box/.style = {draw, text width=22mm, minimum height=11mm, align=center},
pics/adjbox/.style = {
              code = {\node (@adjbox) [box] {#1}; 
                     \coordinate[below=3mm of @adjbox.south west] (-adjb);
                     \coordinate[above=3mm of @adjbox.north east] (adjt);
                     \draw[->] (-adjb) -- (adjt);
                     \coordinate (-in1) at ([yshift=+3mm] @adjbox.west);
                     \coordinate (-in2) at ([yshift=-3mm] @adjbox.west);
                     \coordinate (-out) at (@adjbox.east);}
                     },
        sum/.style = {circle, draw, node contents={}},
                > = Stealth
                        ]
\node (n1) [box] {Reference Model};
\pic  (n2) [below left=of n1.south] {adjbox=Controller};
    \coordinate[left=of n2-in1] (aux1);
    \coordinate[left=of aux1]   (in);
    \draw[->] (in) -- node[above] {$r$} (aux1) -- (n2-in1);
    \draw[->] (aux1) |- (n1);
\node (n3) [box,below right=of n1.south] {Uncertain Plant};
    \coordinate[right=of n3]    (aux2);
    \coordinate[below=of aux2 |- n3.south]  (aux3);
    \draw[->] (aux3) -- (aux3 -| aux1) |- (n2-in2);
    \draw[->] (n2-out) -- (n3);
\node (n4) [sum,right=of aux2];
    \draw[->] (n1) -| (n4)  node [pos=0.9, right] {$x_m$}
                            node [pos=0.9, left] {$+$};                
    \draw[->] (n3) -- (aux2) -- node[above] {$x$} (n4)
                           node [below left] {$-$};
%
\node (n5) [box, below=of n1 |- aux3] {Addaptive Law};
    \draw[->] (aux2) |- ([yshift= 3mm] n5.east);
    \draw[->] (n4)   |- ([yshift=-3mm] n5.east) node[pos=0.05,right] {$e$};
    \draw(n5) -| node[pos=0.1,above] {$\theta$} (n2-adjb);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- Basic tutorial, how to use TikZ is described in chapter *2 Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students* starting on page 31, TikZ & PGF manual, v. 3.1.5.b.
- It is worth to read part III: *TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm* starting on page 123. Specially chapters *16 Arrows* (page 191) *13 Specifying Coordinates* (page 136), *17 Nodes and Edges* (page 224) and *18 Pics: Small Pictures on Paths* (page 263).
- Nodes shapes are described in part V: Libraries.
  for all scheme elements are defined style (`box`, `adjbox` and `>`). For `adjbox` is used small picture `\pic`, which is a bit more tricky than other elementary shapes.
- Definition for `adjbox` are defined one internal coordinate (`adjt`) and four coordinates for connecting `adjbox` to other schemas elements (`-in1`, `-in2`, `-out` and `-adjtb`)
- In drawing of scheme are used relative coordinate system, where distance between nodes are determined by `node distance = <vertical> and <horizontal>`.
- Scheme is drawn from top to bottom and left to right. After each node are drawn connection lines for which are known coordinates.
- For some coordinates, which are not defined by nodes,  are defined by command `coordinate[<relative position>] (<name of coordinate>)`. For some of them are used orthogonal coordinates `|-`, for example `\coordinate[below=of aux2 |- n3.south]  (aux3);`.
- Connection lines are drawn with command `\draw (coordinate 1>) -- (coordinate 2);` when the line is straight or `\draw (<coordinate 1>) |- (coordinate 2>);` when line from `<coordinate 1` go first vertically and than orthogonal to the `<coordinae 2>`.

Comment: Please add a bit of commentary (Ti*k*Z documentation is a weeny bit intimidating...) and/or point at some digestible tutorial(s).