# How can I replicate the following block diagram using TikZ?

Tags: engineering

I am a new to using latex to draw engineering block diagrams. I have wrestled with attempting to create this block diagram

[image]

How can I use Latex to replicate this block diagram. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Where you stuck?

Comment: It would be point less to show you my code because it yielded nothing. I was successful in replicating a simple block diagram, but I am not quite sure how to build upon those concepts to create much more complex diagrams

Comment: well, than you need to hire someone :-) or wait to user, which usually offer service "I-will-do-instead-of-you". Meanwhile see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528733/ can serve you as starting point.

Answer (score 1):

By posting such a question without showing your own attempt you more or less force others who might be willing to help to punch in the texts for you. That is not necessarily a nice thing to do. However, since you seem to be a newcomer, here is a start (also because the suggested start from the link may not contain information on how to do the more tricky parts properly). You need to add the missing texts yourself, and the idea is that such posts enable you to do things on your own.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1ex},
    block/.style={minimum width=#1,align=left,draw,inner ysep=1ex},
    block/.default=8em,font=\sffamily,>=Latex,
    hv/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}}]
 \node[block] (A) {Aircraft\\ longitudinal\\ dyncamics};
 \node[block,above=of A] (A1) {Bla\\ blub};
 \node[block,below=of A] (A2) {Bla\\ blub};
 \path let \p1=($(A.north)-(A.south)$) in
 node[block=5em,left=10em of A,minimum height=\y1] (B) {Pilot};
 \path[every edge/.append style={->}]
 ($(A.north west)!0.5!(B.north east)$) node[below,circ] (C1){}
 ($(A.south west)!0.5!(B.south east)$) node[above,circ] (C2){}
 (C1-|A.east) coordinate (p1) -- (C2-|A.east) coordinate (p4)
 coordinate[pos=1/3] (p2) coordinate[pos=2/3] (p3)  
 foreach \X in {1,...,4} {(p\X) edge ++ (4em,0)}
 node[right=4em of A,align=left]{Aircraft\dots\\ $U,\alpha,\dots$}
 foreach \X in {1,2} {(A\X) edge[hv] (C\X)
 (A\X.east) edge[hv,<-] ++ (1.5em,{pow(-1,\X)*3em}) }
 (C1-|B.east) edge["$\delta_1$"] (C1)
 (C2-|B.east) edge["$\delta_2$"] (C2)
 (C1) edge["$\delta_3$"] (C1-|A.west)
 (C2) edge["$\delta_4$"] (C2-|A.west);
 \draw[dashed,<-] (B.south) |- ($(A2.south east)+(3em,-2em)$) coordinate(aux)
 node[pos=0.75,below] {bla bla}  -- ([yshift=3em]A2-|aux);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]